Why is the query not part of the URI routing?
I checked a few web frameworks like Laravel, Slim, express.js, etc. None of them has support for query string parameters in routing. To clarify I mean I can do router.get('/people/{id}') but not router.get('/people?search={keywords}') even though the second is a valid URI template.
I wonder why this happened. I mean the query string is part of the URI and according to the URI standard the path contains the hierarchical and the query string the non-hierarchical part of the URI. Since the complete URI is the resource identifier, not just the path we should use the query string for routing as well. At least this is my logic.

The query component contains non-hierarchical data that, along with
data in the path component (Section 3.3), serves to identify a
resource ...

https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986#page-23
For example I think /people?search=keywords is a completely valid resource identifier. Still what I can do with these frameworks is router.get('/people') and then an if-else statement in the controller. So the question is what am I missing here, why is the query not part of the routing?

I promise you Laravel (and all the others) supports query strings.

Ignore my previous comment, I kinda see what you're saying now. Laravel supports Query Strings, but not as part of the Router. I.e. you can define Route::get('/people'), but not Route::get('/people?search={search}') (or similar), and you're correct, you'd handle the ?search=example as $search = request()->input('search'); in your Controller. You could also use Route Parameters, like Route::get('/people/{search}'), and in your Controller public function people($search){ ... }. We can't really answer the "Why", since we didn't write the frameworks though ‍♂️

@TimLewis Maybe there are people here who wrote routers and ran into the problem which caused this. I am pretty sure there is a reason, because it is so prevalent in the recent frameworks.

Sorry yeah, it's totally possible someone here might know the reason. The "We" I was referencing was myself and ceejayoz; we're both highly active on laravel-tagged questions, which I mistakenly though this question was asking about specifically (I thought this was tagged laravel, which it is not; clearly I didn't get enough sleep last night lol)

The query string is typically used for filtering or refining data, not deciding which route to take.
Think of routing in web frameworks like finding an address you've never been to before. The street name is like the path in the URL. It gets you to the general area.
GET /streetName
I'd expect an endpoint like this to present me with a list of all the available street numbers and any other important information.
This endpoint would likely map to an index action in a controller.

Once you're on the right street, you start looking at the house numbers to find the exact place you're going, which is like using query strings to refine or filter the results.
GET /streetName?number=1337
or
GET /streetName/1337 (same concept)
I'd expect either of these to give me information specific to the streetName + number.
This endpoint would likely map to a show action in a controller.

